# Finding errors in Mysql Stored Procedure. Unable to understand the error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

What can be the issue in this stored procedure? I have syntax error in this code which I am unable to understand. The sql query inside the code runs perfectly fine but when I try to write it as a stored procedure it throws syntax error.
The error is:

> [ERROR in query 1] PROCEDURE 1bot already exists
>
> [ERROR in query 2] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `1bot`()

BEGIN
SELECT  
COUNT(distinct orders.customer_id) as Total_Customers, 
date_format(orders.created_at,'%M %Y') as month, 
COUNT(orders.`increment_id`) as Unique_single_orders, 
SUM(orders.`base_subtotal`) as total_rev,  
SUM(billing.`total` + 5) as COGS, (
SUM(orders.`base_subtotal`) - SUM(billing.total + 5)) as marketing_expense, 
(AVG(orders.`base_subtotal`) - AVG(billing.total + 5)) as avg_acquisition_cost

FROM `sales_flat_order` as orders

LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` as items on orders.`entity_id` = items.`order_id` 

LEFT JOIN `vingo_billing` as billing on orders.`increment_id` = billing.`order_number`

WHERE orders.`created_at` between '2016-09-01 00:00:00' and '2017-01-23'

AND items.sku LIKE "%1bot%"

AND orders.status != "closed"
and orders.shipping_invoiced != '15'
and billing.total > 0
and orders.`total_qty_ordered` < 2;

END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Including the error message you are seeing would he helpful to those who answering your question.

Comment: Added the error message. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: **PROCEDURE skimm_1_cohort already exists**? That word is not even used in your code :-?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

> PROCEDURE 1bot already exists

This is self-explanatory. You apparently already have created a procedure named `1bot`. MySQL gives you an error because the alternative would be to silently replace the existing procedure with the one you are defining, which may be different. MySQL is protecting you from clobbering a procedure you might need.

If you *want* to clobber the existing procedure and replace it with new code, you must drop it first:

```
DROP PROCEDURE `1bot`;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `1bot`() ...
```

Note that a similar error is given if you try to CREATE TABLE and name a table that already exists.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER'

You should know that the `DELIMITER` statement is only recognized in the `mysql` command-line client. The purpose is to change the statement delimiter, which is normally `;` or `\G`, because otherwise you couldn't define a stored procedure or trigger with a body that contains multiple semicolon-delimited statements.

Whereas in most other interfaces, e.g. phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, or when running SQL statements in an application, you can only run one statement at a time anyway, so there's no chance of ambiguity. Therefore `DELIMITER` is not necessary—and not allowed—in those interfaces.

Comment: I tried to remove the delimeter statement but it still doesn't work. Can you suggest me where I can be going wrong?

Comment: I cannot guess what tool or environment you're using to run these statements, so I can't offer any suggestions.

Comment: I tested the code you wrote using the `mysql` command-line tool, and it works fine. This suggests to me that you're not using that tool. And apparently something went wrong, but you are going to keep that information to yourself. So good luck!